# Invariants in trac's customizable ticket workflow

Tags: trac

I tried looking at the documentation for Trac's (0.12) customizable ticket workflow.

The authors claim that it is completely customizable, but there is something I don't get then. There must be an "initial state" at which tickets start, I guess. Is this hardcoded as "new"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only "new", "closed" is the other hard-coded Trac ticket status.

This was and is so for different reasons, among others these labels are used to do conditional formatting with fixed-name CSS classes, default reports use "not closed" as synonym for open tickets, etc.

As a related note, there is [some work on the way](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/Proposals/ConfigEnumTranslation) to possibly lift this limitation in later versions (Trac 1.2 and beyond). Until then its really better to "work with it rather than against it", as JosefAssad said.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall, this isn't modifiable in trac. The "New" state entry point to workflows is fixed. But you can work with it rather than against it.

I think the way trac is designed, the intent of starting out with an unassigned "New" state is fairly logical, but you need to look at things from a certain perspective which is not always explicitly stated.

Think about the lifecycle of a bug. It is introduced in the code, a user discovers it, the user reports it, a developer is assigned, the developer begins working on it, and so on. I like to think of the "New" state as the part where the bug exists and has just been reported.

When you inform a development team of a bug, they usually won't start working on it right away. The bug still needs to have its severity and technical depth evaluated for example. After you report a bug, the development team still needs to digest your report to know how to introduce it to the bug resolution processes. This in my mind is the intent of the "New" state in trac.

In trac workflows I have designed and worked with, I liked to have the initial state of "Accepted" assign the ticket to a development coordinator who qualifies the ticket and kicks it back and forth with the reporter to improve the report's quality and to figure out where next to send it, which milestone to assign it to, and so on.

So a ticket in a state Assigned is a ticket the development coordinator is working on. A ticket in state New is one the development coordinator has not handled yet.